# HTML target - first click ON THE DIV and after open the second div

Tags: html, target

The sitemap of my page, I set it to click and show a second div (for more infos) when I preview the second div is already open and with the click closes and opens accordingly, I want the first time to display it, to be closed.
(The following example does not work, I do not know why, on m preview web it's ok)

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.sitemapline").click(function(){
        $("div.sitemapfooter").toggle();
      });
});
</script>
```

```css
.sitemapline {
 width:100%;
 border:solid #F00;


}



.sitemapline2 li {
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>sitemap footer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sitemapline">
<div class="sitemapline2"><ul>
<li>Copyright ©.</li>
<li>Privacy Policy</li> 
</ul>
  </div> </div>
  
  
  <div class="sitemapfooter">
<div>
<ul><h2>About Us</h2>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

`tthe first time to display it closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to the top of your script to hide it when the page opens.

```
$(".sitemapfooter").hide();
```

The best way is to use CSS as this will hide the element before the jQuery runs rather than once the DOM has loaded.

CSS

```
.sitemapfooter {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @Jim-miraidev is right. There might be a split second when you still see it when the page opens. CSS is definitely a cleaner answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the inline style of the element to `display: none`, and then it will default to hidden on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.sitemapline").click(function(){
        $("div.sitemapfooter").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.sitemapline {
 width:100%;
 border:solid #F00;
}

.sitemapline2 li {
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>sitemap footer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sitemapline">
<div class="sitemapline2"><ul>
<li>Copyright ©.</li>
<li>Privacy Policy</li> 
</ul>
  </div> </div>
  
  
  <div class="sitemapfooter" style="display: none">
<div>
<ul><h2>About Us</h2>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display: none` to the sitemapfooter div, it will be hidden at startup.

```
.sitemapfooter {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want the second div hidden by default.

In order to make that happen you have to change your css code targeting the class "sitemapline2" and add a display style of none.

This will cause the div with the class "sitemapline2" not to show in the beginning, and when you click the jquery function will run to change the css style to display:block showing your info div.